# Why can I free memory twice, but can't in different situations?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

This is the code I have currently.

```
int main() {
    double *t, *k;
    Item *a = calloc(1, sizeof(Item));
    a->w = malloc(sizeof(double));
    t = a->w;
    k = t;
    free(a->w);
    free(a);
    free(k);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I was able to compile and run without getting any explicit errors. However if I free the pointer, k, before the structure, a, is freed, then I receive a double free/heap corruption error.

```
free(a->w);
free(k);
free(a);
```

Additionally, I receive the same error if I do:

```
free(k);
free(a->w);
free(a);
```

Why is it that I can free the pointer, k after the structure has been freed without any explicit errors, but I cannot free the memory k is pointing twice until the structure a is freed?

Comment: Your a playing with *fire*. You should receive a *double-free or corruption* error. It is up to you to insure you are not freeing the same memory twice.

Comment: Double-free is illegal but the system is not required to diagnose it. It can just corrupt memory silently.

Comment: Yeah. I understand it is up to me to make sure I don't free the same memory twice, but I was just curious why I don't receive a double-free/corruption error in the first segment of code, but I do for the other two. Would it be a compiler thing?

Comment: It is **undefined behaviour**. There is nothing interesting in it. It just proves that in C your broken code might seem to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means anything can happen, such as appearing to work, crashing immediately, crashing at some point later, or strange unexpected behavior, or the often mentioned [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free):

> free() frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must  have 
>   been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). 
>   Otherwise, **or  if  free(ptr)  has  already  been  called  before, 
>   undefined behaviour occurs**.  If ptr is NULL, no operation is
>   performed.

So triggering a double-free error may occur but is not required.